# Android / Java Rewriting file makes it empty?

Tags: java, android

I am writing to file every 10 second in my application, I need to save data regardless of user input. The file writing code goes as follows,

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(CurrentContext.getFilesDir() +  File.separator + "myFile")); 
fos.write(s.toString().getBytes()); 
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do not use the constructor with the `append` parameter, the file is every time created new (and empty).

```
public FileOutputStream(String name)
```

vs.

```
public FileOutputStream(String name,boolean append)
```

[FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)

Comment: so if I use it with false, would it completely rewrite the file?

Answer (score 3):

Just open the FileOutputStream in append mode as follows:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(CurrentContext.getFilesDir() +  File.separator + "myFile"), true); // The extra boolean at the end specifies append-mode
fos.write(s.toString().getBytes()); 
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```